# How should one write the import procedures in a module that uses imported modules in a limited way?

Tags: python, function, import, module, partial

I have a module that features numerous functions. Some of these functions are dependent on other modules. The module is to be used in some environments that are not going to have these other modules. In these environments, I want the functionality of the module that is not dependent on these other unavailable modules to be usable. What is a reasonable way of coding this?

I am happy for an exception to be raised when a function's dependency module is not met, but I want the module to be usable for other functions that do not have dependency problems.

At present, I'm thinking of a module-level function something like the following:

```
tryImport(moduleName = None):
    try:
        module = __import__(moduleName)
        return(module)
    except: 
        raise(Exception("module {moduleName} import error".format(
            moduleName = moduleName)))
        sys.exit()
```

This would then be used within functions in a way such as the following:

```
def function1():
    pyfiglet = tryImport(moduleName = "pyfiglet")
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, it sounds like there's nothing wrong with putting the imports you need inside functions, rather than at the top of your module (don't worry, it costs virtually nothing to reimport):

```
def some_function():
    import foo # Throws if there is no foo
    return foo.bar ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Full stop, please.

The first thing is that the problem you described indicates that you should redesign your module. The most obvious solution is to break it into a couple of modules in one package. Each of them would contain group of functions with common external dependencies. You can easily define how many groups you need if you only know which dependencies might be missing on the target machine. Then you can import them separately. Basically in a given environment you import only those you need and the problem doesn't exist anymore.

If you still believe it's not the case and insist on keeping all the functions in one module then you can always do something like:

```
if env_type == 'env1':
    import pyfiglet
if env_type in ('env1', 'env2'):
    import pynose
    import gzio
```

How you deduct the env_type is up to you. Might come from some configuration file or the environment variable.
Then you have your functions in this module. No problem occurs if none of the module consumers calls function which makes use of the module which is unavailable in a given environment.
I don't see any point in throwing your custom exception. `NameError` exception will be thrown anyway upon trial to access not imported name. By the way your `sys.exit()` would never be executed anyway.

If you don't want to define environment types, you can still achieve the goal with the following code:

```
try: import pyfiglet
except ImportError: pass
try: import pynose
except ImportError: pass
try: import gzio
except ImportError: pass
```

Both code snippets are supposed to be used on module level and not inside functions.

**TL;DR** I would just break this module into several parts. But if you really have to keep it monolithic, just use the basic language features and don't over-engineer it by using `__import__` and a dedicated function.